# TransactionScope causes TransactionManagerCommunicationException when used for DB unit tests

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing, transactionscope

I'd like to run some tests of stored procedures in my database without actually affecting the data (or, to put it more exactly, without a lasting impact after the test has run).

After some research I came up with the approach of using TransactionScope within my Visual Studio 2010 test project such as

```
using( new TransactionScope())
{
    using( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("someConnectionString"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using( SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand( "some sql", connection ))
        {
            // Do some database stuff...
        }
     }
}
```

Now this works fine as long as I put all of this within a single test method, i.e. all my changes to the database are automatically rolled back when the using block for TransactionScope is finished.

My problem is now that I'd like to do some database stuff in ClassInitialize so I only have to do it once per test class and not for every test method. When I create a public TransactionScope property and assign it an instance of TransactionScope in the ClassInitialize method, this works okay. As soon as I do any database related stuff in one of my test methods, I run into a TransactionManagerCommunicationException within that method.

I don't quite understand why that is the case, and I'd also like to know whether there is a mistake in my approach or how I can get it to work without having to set up the TransactionScope including all set up stuff for the tests within each test method again.

**EDIT**

Code excerpt below, I hope this gives enough information:

```
public TransactionScope Scope { get; set; }

[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInitialize( TestContext testContext )
{
    Scope = new TransactionScope();
    // Do some db set up stuff, e.g. create records used for tests etc.
}

[ClassCleanup]
public static void ClassCleanup()
{
    Scope.Dispose();
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    using( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( "someConnectionString" ) )
    {
        DataTable result = new DataTable();
        using( SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand( "spName", connection ) )
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using( SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter() )
            {
                adapter.SelecteCommand = command;
                // The next line causes the exception to be thrown
                adapter.Fill( result );
            }
        }

        // Assertions against DataTable result
    }
}
```

The exception is

---

TransactionManagerCommunicationException was unhandled by user code
Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool.

---

I understand that I could try and change the settings, but I do not understand why I get the exception to begin with - what is different compared to having the code above in a single (test) method?

Thanks in advance and

best regards

G.

Comment: Can you provide more details from the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exception is saying that MSDTC isn't enabled.  My guess is that when you were using TransactionScope individually, it was just creating local SQL transactions -- which don't require DTC.  However, when you share a TransactionScope over multiple connections, the transaction gets "promoted" to a distributed transaction through the DTC, which you may not have enabled.

Try enabling network access on MSDTC on your local machine and the server.  The steps for doing so vary a little depending on your OS. [Here's how to do it in Win 2003 Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817064).  [Here's a link for Win 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753510%28WS.10%29.aspx).  Note that you will likely need to enable DTC through your firewalls as well (explained in the last link...)

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction - as soon as I opened more than one connection I got the exception, so I created a public Connection property that I could reuse from my different methods. 

What I also found out when I changed my code was how to avoid an InvalidOperationException in the Cleanup method, I had to move the calls to create and dispose the TransactionScope to the methods marked with [TestInitialize] and [TestCleanup] rather than their Class equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your setup something like this:

```
void Main()
{
   using(new SetupTransaction())
   {
    //Your test
   }
}

public class SetupTransaction : IDisposable
{
    private TransactionScope transaction;

    public SetupTransaction()
    {
        transaction = new TransactionScope();
        //Do your stuff here
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        transaction.Dispose();
    }
}
```

As for the error you're getting, could you post exactly how you're using your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

One approach I have used with success is creating a base class that implements setup and teardown. Within the setup method you create a new transaction scope and store it in a private class variable. Within the teardown method you rollback the transaction scope.

I'm using NUNit, but the principle should be the same for MSTest. The clue here is that `SetUp` and `TearDown` executes once before and after **each** unit test to ensure isolation among unit tests.

Also, as @blech mentions, the Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC) service must be running for this solution to work.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But doesn't this approach end up with the same problem when starting the TransactionScope in one (set up) method, calling another (test) method and then disposing it in the cleanup (teardown)? The equivalents to NUnit exist as ClassInitialize (TestFixtureSetup) and TestInitialize (SetUp) as well as their corresponding TearDown counterparts (ClassCleanup, TestCleanup).

Comment: @Gorgsenegger - probably. Have you tested using `TestInitialize` and `TestCleanup`?

Comment: @Peter Lillevold I didn't understand the difference of using a transaction in a base class vs using it directly in the current test class. Are you talking about code reuse or something else?

Comment: @satyajit - its for code reuse, which also have the nice side effect that unit tests will be cleaner.